# How to automatically ssh into server and su with password using bash script?

Tags: bash, ssh, server, passwords, su

I need to ssh into a server and su with password within that server and then ssh into another server from there. I am not able to su with password after I ssh into my first server via bash script. Normally what I do in terminal is,

$ ssh server1

logged in  to server1$ su user

password: ******

switched to corresponding user$ ssh server2

How can I automate this process by switching user with password in bash?

Comment: This seems like an odd setup to begin with. Why can't you just login to user2@server1? If you can't, for whatever reason, then you can use the `.bashrc` to accomplish your task.

Comment: I need to login to user @server1 using a bash script but am not sure about doing that! Its raising issues like "su must be run from another terminal"

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

`sshpass -f <(printf '%s\n' "yourpassword") ssh username@server "\"sshpass -f <(printf '%s\n' "yourpassword") ssh username@server"`

Comment: Maybe something along these lines.... I would test but I haven't got any servers that I can use atm.

Comment: Thanks but how can I pass the password?

Comment: What about using sshpass? `sshpass -p 'YourPassword' ssh user@host`

Comment: So, I tried sshpass -p 'YourPassword' ssh user@host and then "su user" its not it is asking password in the terminal

Comment: ssh username@server1 "su -c \"sshpass -p 'YourPassword' ssh user@server2"su -c"" is there any syntax issues? is is showing unexpected EOF

Comment: This isn't working for me! but am able to do till the 2nd step using,                  ssh -tt user@host "su user "        This will ask password in the terminal after I enter the password it will switch to that user..... after that I need to do one more ssh how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Can sudo without password works for you?

```
ssh abc@$xyz "
    echo '
        set -vxe
        # Your script here
    ' | sudo /bin/bash"
```